# Error implementing Facebook external login in ASP.NET core application

Tags: facebook, asp.net-core

- I'm trying to create an external login through Facebook, generated the `AppId` and `AppSecret` and configured it in the `program.cs` file. I've also done one for Google as shown

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddGoogle(googleOptions =>
    {
        googleOptions.ClientId = "xxx";
        googleOptions.ClientSecret = "xxx";
    })
    .AddFacebook(facebookOptions =>
    {
        facebookOptions.AppId = "xxx";
        facebookOptions.AppSecret = "xxx";
        //facebookOptions.CallbackPath = "/signin-facebook";
    });
```

- I'm hosting the app on my local machine. When I click the facebook login button, and after entering Facebook credentials, and error page pops up

[The error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9Sqv.png)

- Another thing I'd like to add is that when I tried debugging the issue, the `ExternalLogin` action method was hit but the control never got to the `ExternalLoginCallback` action method which will sign the user in.
- Note that the login through Google works.

Any help/suggestions will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: [Everything works fine with the official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/facebook-logins?view=aspnetcore-8.0), please provide more detailed steps so that we can reproduce the issue.